# apache https is getting redirect to http

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have configured https-vhosts.conf file in apache to point to non-standard port

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"                   ####this is needed for our app
  ServerName test.apa.com
  ProxyPass / http://10.1.1.5:8443
  ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.1.5:8443
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I try to access url in chrome: https://test.apa.com:8081 , i get below error:
[image]

Also, the url in  address bar shows as http://test.apa.com:8081.However, when I change http to https and try to access...it works fine and browser shows https://test.apa.com:8081.

Please suggest on what the issue is with the configuration of virtual hosts?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form. Also, the error message shown matches your problem description quite well. Make sure you don't get the protocol corrected by your browser's autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Listen 8081
> ```

Since you are using a non-standard port for HTTPS, you need to specify this in the `Listen` directive, otherwise it defaults to `http`. (`https` is only the default when using the standard 443 port.)

For example:

```
Listen 8081 https
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen